# python: tarfile same content different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar

consider the following code:

```py
import tarfile
from os import unlink
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep

dir0 = Path("/tmp/a")
dir0.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
fil0 = dir0 / "eph0"
fil0.write_text("Text 0", encoding="UTF-8")
fil1 = dir0 / "eph1"
fil1.write_text("Text 1", encoding="UTF-8")
fil2 = dir0 / "eph2"
fil2.write_text("Text 2", encoding="UTF-8")


# Python
tgz = "/tmp/py.tgz"
with tarfile.open(tgz, "w:gz") as tar_obj:
    tar_obj.add("/tmp/a", arcname="a")
out = Popen(f"sha256sum {tgz}", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print(out)

sleep(5)
unlink(tgz)

tgz = "/tmp/py.tgz"
with tarfile.open(tgz, "w:gz") as tar_obj:
    tar_obj.add("/tmp/a", arcname="a")
out = Popen(f"sha256sum {tgz}", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print(out)


# CMD - tar
tgz = "/tmp/tar_a0.tgz"
_ = Popen(f"tar czf {tgz} /tmp/a", shell=True, stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
out = Popen(f"sha256sum {tgz}", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print(out)

sleep(5)

tgz = "/tmp/tar_a1.tgz"
_ = Popen(f"tar czf {tgz} /tmp/a", shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out = Popen(f"sha256sum {tgz}", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print(out)


# CMD - gzip
tgz = "/tmp/gzp_a0.tgz"
_ = Popen(f"tar -c /tmp/a | gzip -n >{tgz}", shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out = Popen(f"sha256sum {tgz}", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print(out)

sleep(5)

tgz = "/tmp/gzp_a1.tgz"
_ = Popen(f"tar -c /tmp/a | gzip -n >{tgz}", shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out = Popen(f"sha256sum {tgz}", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print(out)
```

I am creating a folder, some files and compress using the `tarfile` module and the `tar` command.

The output is:

```
b'5b18528dde6c18897159b8e2d6d26e0ab95972f4206bbd01ad0deef2d64d8d6c  /tmp/py.tgz\n'
b'32b45721ea88a9c0d787d4f13687e606fdf14eea5aa9fdabb3860416f7fb6136  /tmp/py.tgz\n'
b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  /tmp/tar_a0.tgz\n'
b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  /tmp/tar_a1.tgz\n'
b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  /tmp/gzp_a0.tgz\n'
b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  /tmp/gzp_a1.tgz\n'
```

Using the command line I get always the same file, instead using the `tarfile` module the output is different every time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The first python file containts `a0.tgz` and the second `a1.tgz`, i.e. the name is obviously stored there. I don't know the tar file format to explain why the other two files are the same. Anyway, you are creating a plain archives with `tar cf`, not a gzipped `.tgz` files.

Comment: I have tried using the same name with `tarfile` and the `sha256sum` are different anyway. Using `czf` instead of `cf` returns the same behaviour.

Comment: Similar question (answered): https://serverfault.com/questions/110208/different-md5sums-for-same-tar-contents

Comment: Those two files are same after decompression. This confirms the linked answer from `serverfault.com` that the `gzip` header is responsible for the difference.

Comment: Could you look at my updated post?

Comment: I have tried multiple times: `tar`/`gzip` return always the same hash, `tarfile` change every time (some content, different timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by VPfB, the problem is that the `mtime` field is different every time the files are created, even if the content is the same.

The `tar` command discards this information by default.

Instead the `tarfile` python module does not do it by default, but you can set it using the `filter` argument:

```py
import tarfile

def reset(tarinfo):
    tarinfo.uid = tarinfo.gid = 0
    tarinfo.uname = tarinfo.gname = "root"
    tarinfo.mtime = 1
    return tarinfo

with tarfile.open("/tmp/a.tar", "w:xz") as tar_obj:
    tar_obj.add("/tmp/a", arcname="a", filter=reset)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this difference is that when you call `tar cf` you **do not** zip the content, you only archive it.

On the opposite, the `tarfile` module, by default, gunzip the content inside the archive and name the inside zipped archive the same way the main archive is named (so here a0.tgz and a1.tgz).

And the "zipped content" has two different names, therefore cryptographic hash is different.

Comment: Could you look at the my Update 1 version?